# DacServices.GenerateDriftReport throws sql server version Conflict

Tags: sql-server, dacpac, data-tier-applications

I have a microsoft sql server 2014 instance with a database "myDB". In SSMS I have registered this database as Datatier application. I have installed the latest dacfx with nuget to my visual studio project. When I hit DacServices.GenerateDriftReport("myDB") it throws:

> Databases registered as a DAC database must be hosted by an instance of SQL 2005 SP4, SQL 2008 SP2, SQL 2008 R2, SQL 2012 or SQL Azure.

Also the method DacServices.Unregister throws this error.

I am installing Windows Server Updates to the SQL Server machine but I don't believe this would fix it.

Comment: What version of DacFx are you using? Is it the June release (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43370)? Do other operations such as deploy / extract work OK?

Comment: It is the June 2014 Release. The deployment works, yes.