# DACPAC not deploying to Azure SQL Database V12

Tags: sql-server, azure, dacpac

I've created an new SQL V12 database on azure. I've been enabled to update that database once to the model we have in our database project. We did this by using the 'Register as Data-tier Application' in SQL Management Studio.

Now we have an update on our model and we want to update our database again with a new DACPAC. When we use the function 'Upgrade Data-tier Application' (again trough SQL Management Studio) we get the error message:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Databases registered as a DAC database must be hosted by an instance
>   of SQL 2005 SP4, SQL 2008 SP2, SQL 2008 R2, SQL 2012, SQL 2014 or
>   Microsoft Azure SQL Database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Unable to proceed with DAC operations on the target instance because
>   it does not support DACs. Specify another instance, or upgrade to a
>   version that supports DACs. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

Very strange notification cause the database is already registered as Data-tier application and has been deployed once. I can't find any logs giving more details.

Our Database project has the target platform: "Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12" so that is the correct one.

Comment: May be same as [trouble connecting through Active directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891308/dacservices-generatedriftreport-throws-sql-server-version-conflict)

Answer (score 0):

Did you get anywhere with this? I'm encountering the same error. Need Azure SQL V12 so I can include Always Encrypted CMK/CEK and column encryption settings with the dacpac. Also, I'm deploying to a

I tried deploying from SSMS 17.2 and VS2015 w/ SSDT 14.0.61021.0 with no success.
I had originally published to the same DB with the DACPAC target as "Azure SQL Database" (not V12). Then later needed to change to V12 so I could build the dacpac with CEKs, CMKs and column encryption settings. After changing to V12 I started getting the same failure message.

I was able to publish for V12 target from VS2015 SSDT to the existing DB if I unchecked the "Register as Data-tier application" checkbox.
Also, I created a new DB and made my first dacpac deployment the one targeting V12 and it succeeded as well. I would think the dac framework would be able to handle the target Azure SQL DB to Azure SQL DB V12, but it seems not.

Hope this helps you or someone else that runs into this.

Comment: *"I'm deploying to a"* - deploying to a *what*?